# Что такое SMBv1 SMBv2 SMBv3

Tags: администрирование, samba, smb

Пришла политика на пк в которой отключают SMBv1, компьютера в домене.
Почитал, в общих чертах понял что это закрытие шар.
Но я не пойму разницу между версиями, какую испольщую я для  хранение удалённых бэкапов. Так же обращение к удалённым файлам в виде \servername\share
Можете более просто объяснить что это и чего ожидать после закрытие SMBv1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`smb1` - это [xp](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP). [7](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7) и выше нормально пашут на `v2` и выше. Закрывать 1-ю версию надо от `Petya` про которого даже на [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petya) написано. Из того что 99% отвалится - сетевые МФУ, которые умели печатать в общие папки не по `ftp`. Тут либо [filezilla server](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server) поднимать, либо дёргать производителей МФУ на наличие новых прошивок.